# Remove header while merging multiple .csv files using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have written the code to concatenate sample files into a single file minus the headers each file.

**Input files:**

**File1:**

> ```
> [ Row : Header ],,,,,,,,,
> ContractNum,ProgramNum,CustomerNum,TierNum,StartDate,EndDate,DateCreated,CreatedBy,DateUpdated,UpdatedBy
> 00032116,21238,60304PRMI,3,2014-05-02,2017-09-30,Administrator,Administrator,2016-02-29 10:46:14,2016-02-29 10:46:14
> 00032116,21238,81790PRMI,3,2014-05-02,2017-09-30,Administrator,Administrator,2016-02-29 10:46:14,2016-02-29 10:46:14
> ```

**File 2:**

> ```
> [ Row : Header ],,,,,,,,,
> ContractNum,ProgramNum,CustomerNum,TierNum,StartDate,EndDate,DateCreated,CreatedBy,DateUpdated,UpdatedBy
> 00024067,15562,9942PRMI,1,2014-09-16,2016-12-31,gintgUser,gintgUser,2016-02-21 05:59:43,2016-02-21 05:59:43
> ```

**Expected Output:**

> ```
> [ Row : Header ],,,,,,,,,
> ContractNum,ProgramNum,CustomerNum,TierNum,StartDate,EndDate,DateCreated,CreatedBy,DateUpdated,UpdatedBy
> 00024067,15562,9942PRMI,1,2014-09-16,2016-12-31,gintgUser,gintgUser,2016-02-21 05:59:43,2016-02-21 05:59:43
> 00032116,21238,60304PRMI,3,2014-05-02,2017-09-30,Administrator,Administrator,2016-02-29 10:46:14,2016-02-29 10:46:14
> 00032116,21238,81790PRMI,3,2014-05-02,2017-09-30,Administrator,Administrator,2016-02-29 10:46:14,2016-02-29 10:46:14
> ```

**Actual Output:**

> ```
> [ Row : Header ],,,,,,,,,
> ContractNum,ProgramNum,CustomerNum,TierNum,StartDate,EndDate,DateCreated,CreatedBy,DateUpdated,UpdatedBy
> 00024067,15562,9942PRMI,1,2014-09-16,2016-12-31,gintgUser,gintgUser,2016-02-21 05:59:43,2016-02-21 05:59:43
> 00032116,21238,60304PRMI,3,2014-05-02,2017-09-30,Administrator,Administrator,2016-02-29 10:46:14,2016-02-29 10:46:14
> [ Row : Header ],,,,,,,,,
> ContractNum,ProgramNum,CustomerNum,TierNum,StartDate,EndDate,DateCreated,CreatedBy,DateUpdated,UpdatedBy
> 00032116,21238,81790PRMI,3,2014-05-02,2017-09-30,Administrator,Administrator,2016-02-29 10:46:14,2016-02-29 10:46:14
> ```

Please find below code used for this operation:

```
@echo off
break>Combined.csv
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if exist C:\Users\kartikeya.avasthi\Desktop\Batch_Scripts\Combined.csv del C:\Users\kartikeya.avasthi\Desktop\Batch_Scripts\Combined.csv

dir /a-d /b C:\Users\kartikeya.avasthi\Desktop\Batch_Scripts\ContractEligibility_*.csv>C:\Users\kartikeya.avasthi\Desktop\Batch_Scripts\dirfiles.txt

cd C:\Users\kartikeya.avasthi\Desktop\Batch_Scripts\

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (C:\Users\kartikeya.avasthi\Desktop\Batch_Scripts\dirfiles.txt) do (
    set /p header=<%%A
    if "!header!" neq "" (
        (echo(!header!)>Combined.csv
        goto :break_for
    )

)
:break_for

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (C:\Users\kartikeya.avasthi\Desktop\Batch_Scripts\dirfiles.txt) do (
        more +1 %%A>>Combined.csv
   )

del dirfiles.txt
}
```

Can someone please help me resolve this issue. I am a neophyte to batch scripting and unable to debug this issue.

Comment: Please learn how to format code portions properly; use the `{}` button in the editir region...

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/19592600/3664960

Comment: I improved formatting of the same CSV files -- see my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36325776/5047996/3); note that I removed a truncated line from sample file 2, because I considered it a copy-paste error, and that line did not occur in the sample output files; if I did something wrong, feel free to edit the post once again...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Batch file execution error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36057140/windows-batch-file-execution-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for an interim file that contains a list of CSV files, you can read and combine them by a standard `for` loop and a nested `for /F` loop, using its `skip` option to get rid of the headers (assuming the header is always a single line). The initial header can be taken from another `for`/`for /F` loop construct that is broken upon its first iteration:

```
> "C:\Users\kartikeya.avasthi\Desktop\Batch_Scripts\Combined.csv" (
    for %%F in ("C:\Users\kartikeya.avasthi\Desktop\Batch_Scripts\ContractEligibility_*.csv") do (
        for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%L in ("%%~F") do (
            echo(%%L
            goto :LEAVE
        )
    )
)
:LEAVE
>> "C:\Users\kartikeya.avasthi\Desktop\Batch_Scripts\Combined.csv" (
    for %%F in ("C:\Users\kartikeya.avasthi\Desktop\Batch_Scripts\ContractEligibility_*.csv") do (
        for /F "usebackq skip=1 eol=| delims=" %%L in ("%%~F") do (
            echo(%%L
        )
    )
)
```

---

If you need a specific sort order of the CSV files, you need another `for /F` loop instead of the standard `for` loop that parses the output of a `dir /B` command to do that job. The following example takes a two-line header, then it sorts the files from oldest to newest modification dates:

```
> "C:\Users\kartikeya.avasthi\Desktop\Batch_Scripts\Combined.csv" (
    set "FLAG="
    for %%F in ("C:\Users\kartikeya.avasthi\Desktop\Batch_Scripts\ContractEligibility_*.csv") do (
        for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%L in ("%%~F") do (
            echo(%%L
            if defined FLAG goto :LEAVE
            set "FLAG=#"
        )
    )
)
:LEAVE
>> "C:\Users\kartikeya.avasthi\Desktop\Batch_Scripts\Combined.csv" (
    for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('
        dir /B /A:-D /O:D /T:W "C:\Users\kartikeya.avasthi\Desktop\Batch_Scripts\ContractEligibility_*.csv"
    ') do (
        for /F "usebackq skip=2 eol=| delims=" %%L in ("%%F") do (
            echo(%%L
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: thanks for the above is there some way to pick up the header in the first for loop from the third line onwards. Also am new as a user to the community so thanks you for the formatting updates much appreciated.

Comment: @kartikeya_aj, so the header spans over lines 1 and 2 (like your sample data show)? see my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36327709/5047996/2) (coming soon)...

Comment: Alright... the samples in your question show two rows/lines, so it doesn't make sense to adapt my answer... anyway, you got the idea how to do it; you could also use a counter, say `COUNT`, whih you increment in the 1st loop like `set /A COUNT+=1`, and then leave the loop conditionalls like `if !COUNT! EQU 3 goto :LEAVE`; as you can see (`!COUNT!`) you'll need delayed expansion then...

Comment: Thanks for this solution

Answer (score 1):

A couple points about this question:

- This question is an exact duplicate of [Windows Batch file execution error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36057140/windows-batch-file-execution-error/)
- At that question there are 4 answers, one of which is mine.
- In my answer I asked you to post a small section of your data files, but you never replied.
- This is a copy of my answer at that question after I slightly modified it in order to insert the key point of your problem: *the headers contain TWO lines*:

**EDIT**: I modified the code accordingly to the *new* specifications posted in a comment: there are *three lines* of headers in each file, but just the 3rd must be included in the output.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cls

REM cd C:\Users\kartikeya.avasthi\Desktop\Batch_Scripts\

set "header3="
(for %%A in (*.csv) do (

   if not defined header3 (
      (set /p "header1=" & set /p "header2=" & set /p "header3=") <%%A
      echo !header3!
   )

   more +3 %%A

)) > Combined.txt
```

- And this is the generated Combined.txt file when this program run with your data above:

.

```
[ Row : Header ],,,,,,,,,
ContractNum,ProgramNum,CustomerNum,TierNum,StartDate,EndDate,DateCreated,CreatedBy,DateUpdated,UpdatedBy
00032116,21238,60304PRMI,3,2014-05-02,2017-09-30,Administrator,Administrator,2016-02-29 10:46:14,2016-02-29 10:46:14
00032116,21238,81790PRMI,3,2014-05-02,2017-09-30,Administrator,Administrator,2016-02-29 10:46:14,2016-02-29 10:46:14
00024067,15562,9942PRMI,1,2014-09-16,2016-12-31,gintgUser,gintgUser,2016-02-21 05:59:43,2016-02-21 05:59:43
```

As you can see, the output is the same you want.

**EDIT**: I can't test the modification because the posted input files does *not* contain the same data as the real files...

- You should follow up the questions you post and not post new questions with the exact same problem of a previous one.
- You should be clearer in the description of your problem and post an example data.

Comment: @aanici: As you said that I need to repost my doubt as a different question I did the same. I am sorry if this infringes the rules of the forum i was unaware of the same should i remove this question? Also, Thank you for your help. are actually three header lines the first is a white space followed by the two row header and data from 4th line. I have to skip the first two lines and pick header from 3rd i have tried the following{for /f "tokens=* skip=2" %%A in (C:\Users\kartikeya.avasthi\Desktop\Batch_Scripts\dirfiles.txt) do (
} but it doesn't work

Comment: **1.** I _never_ said that you need to repost a different question! I said: _"post a small section of your files... Please, edit the question, do NOT post additional data in comments!"_ (you may reread [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36057140/windows-batch-file-execution-error/36064379#comment60158294_36064379)). It is bad netiquette to just abandon an open question with no further replies (like a conversation).

Comment: **2.** Perhaps you didn't realized yet that the core point of this question is about the headers: there are three lines of headers and just the 3rd must be included in the output. However, such an important information does _not_ appear in the question, but in comments (_"please, do NOT post additional data in comments!"_). You should include that information in **THIS QUESTION** (_NOT_ in a new one). How? _"Edit the question"_. How? Via the "edit" grey link that appear below the question, immediately below the `windows` and `batch-file` blue tags (between "share" and "close").

Comment: **3.** If your data files have three lines of headers (the first one is empty), why such lines does _not_ appear in your posted input files? The purpose of post example data is that we can access _the SAME data_ you have. If you modify your data when you post it, the posted data serve for nothing...  **4.** I don't understand why you ask me about a `for /f` command that does _NOT_ appear in _my code_! Anyway, if you just said that "are actually three header lines", why did you used "skip=2"? ("three" is _not_ "2").  **5.** I modified my solution accordingly to the _new_ headers specifications.

Comment: Thanks for these comments will keep them in mind and not  to repeat them as well :) . The solution works too. I think that the white space got edited out by someone.I'll add those.thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you felt like installing `awk` - one of the handiest programs around from Unix/Linux - your task would become very simple. It is available for Windows from [here](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net).

Then you could just use:

```
awk  'NR<3 || FNR>2'  *.csv
```

To explain the command, you need to know that `NR` is the `Number of the Record` (i.e. the line number) and it starts at one for the first record/line of the first file and then increments with each record, so it will be less than 3 for just the first two records of just the very first file. `FNR` on the other hand, is the `File Number of Record` which is the same, but it resets to one as each new file is opened, so it will be less than 2 for the first two records of every file.

So, in summary, the command says... *"Print any line if it is one of the very first two lines of all the input files, or if it is past line 2 of any of the files."*

Note that you may need to replace the single quotes with double quotes on Windows.

Note that if you were to download `gawk`, it will work just the same as `awk` for this example.